# JSon parsing error in worklight

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

We are facing the following issue while parsing the JSON response,

The JSON message which we are getting from the back-end looks as below,

```
"Envelope": {
      "Body": {
         "mainpgmResponse": {
            "ns": "http:\/\/mainpgm.wsbeans.iseries\/xsd",
            **"return": {**
               "COUNT": "",
               "OBJNAME": "",
               "OPTION": "",
               "OUTPUTY": "",
               "STATUS": ""
            }
         }
      },
      "soapenv": "http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/"
   },
```

We are trying to parse the JSON content as below,

```
*var webs_data = response.invocationResult.Envelope.Body.mainpgmResponse;

var output = webs_data.return;*
```

The issue is  "return" which is a JavaScript function and hence it is throwing syntax error. We were unable to bye-pass the variable hierarchy.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not simply write:

```
var output = webs_data["return"];
```

Accessing it in an "assoc array-like" syntax will avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is working now and we could able to parse the content.

Comment: No problem :) Please accept the answer, so this problem will appear to be solved